# How can I format a pivot table with staggered elements to make narrower?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, pivot-table

Right now a typical pivot table looks like this: [image]

This takes up too much room horizontally.  I want to format it so that it is narrower and taller, by moving nested blocks down and left.

How can I format it so it looks like this:

```
Conifer
  Cedar
    Cedar, E. Wht. -- Skybound
      #10 Growbag (42 qt)
        12-24 in.           1    %120
        2-3 ft             17    $120
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pivot table in Google Sheets is almost impossible to format, it drives me nuts! Often I use Query instead. I'm not sure if that will work for you your example, but take a look here on the example sheet here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/zLQMJAtsNLo;context-place=forum/docs

Comment: The downside of using a query is that queries are almost a 'write only' language with their escaped multiple systems syntax, AND they aren't gracious about changes in the source table. I have a pivot table that is 6 layers deep (hence the original request).  I am not looking forward with joy and bliss creating a querry to do this.